# Get chain name in hardhat (not chainId)

Tags: solidity, hardhat

In hardhat, you can get the `chainId` by calling `await getChainId()`. However, I'm looking for the chain name. Is there a way to get the chain name without explicitly creating a mapping myself?

EDIT: You can only use this `getChainId` functionality with [hardhat-deploy](https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardhat **core package** doesn't include any map from `chainId` to the chain name.

But:

- They have a mapping in the Etherscan integration package ([GitHub source](https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/blob/master/packages/hardhat-etherscan/src/network/prober.ts#L19)).
- You can define the map in your application according to the [EIP-155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md) where the list of chain IDs was first introduced, or the [expanded list](https://chainid.network/chains.json) (anyone can add to this list - [GitHub](https://github.com/ethereum-lists/chains)).

Answer (score 1):

using 31337 works sometime

```
localhost: {
      url: "<add URL here from terminal>",
      // don't need to give account // thanks to hardhat
      chainId: 31337,
    },
```